# What's the correct way to use tf.data.Dataset.map?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have audio files and I'd like to make a `tf.DataSet` from their audio content (i.e. each audio file in the dataset should be represented as a vector of float values)

Here's my code

```py
def convert_audio_file_to_numpy_array(filepath):
  sample_rate = sox.file_info.sample_rate(filepath)
  audio, sr = librosa.load(filepath, sr=sample_rate)
  array = np.asarray(audio)
  return array

filenames_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(input_filepaths)
waveforms_ds = filenames_ds.map(convert_audio_file_to_numpy_array, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

This produces this error: `TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not Tensor`

I'm using `DataSet`'s `map` function following the pattern in [this official tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/faf1532b3aa7e4bc64c01a164d84f768d1121712/site/en/tutorials/audio/simple_audio.ipynb) (see the call to `files_ds.map`). In it, the function that `map` uses takes a filepath.

What am I doing differently to the official tutorial?

Comment: Please provide the full error traceback.

Comment: The problem is that the function `sox.file_info.sample_rate` expects a string or a Path, but the values in your dataset are Tensors (of type string). If you want to load things from a string Tensor, you need to use `tf.io` functions or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the function `def sample_rate(input_filepath: Union[str, Path]) -> float:` expects either a `string` of a `pathlib.Path`, and you are providing a `Tensor`. (The elements of your `filename_ds` are Tensors of type string).

In the tensorflow tutorial, they load the data with a tensorflow functions that expects a `Tensor` of type string. You should check if you can load your files with `tf.audio` native functions.

Otherwise, a common workaround is to use a generator with `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`, something akin to the following solution:

```
def generator_func(list_of_path):
  
  def convert_audio_file_to_numpy_array(filepath):
    sample_rate = sox.file_info.sample_rate(filepath)
    audio, sr = librosa.load(filepath, sr=sample_rate)
    array = np.asarray(audio)
    return array

  for path in list_of_path:
    yield convert_audio_file_to_numpy_array(path)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator_func, output_types=tf.float32)
```